# How to grep in multiple directories / environment variables consisting of multiple directories?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

is there a way to grep in multiple different directories. Not just recursively in subdirectories. But like in an environment variable like this`PATH=§PATH:$HOME\projects\rails:$HOME\projects\ruby` ?

And then

```
§ grep -iRn "def method(a, b)" $PATH
```

Comment: split the variable on `:` and pass to `grep` as arguments. Ie. `tr` and `xargs`. Or even just `xargs -d:`

Comment: Something is wrong if your `PATH` contains backslashes instead of forward slashes on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily with an array.

```sh
files=($(tr ':' '\n' <<<"$PATH"))
grep -iRn "def method(a, b)" "${files[@]}"
```

This is somewhat error-prone in that it could break in interesting ways if you have e.g. quoted spaces in your `PATH`; but let's assume you don't.